# CSS Flexbox - Image alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm handling a simple flexbox-based banner, which is working almost perfectly. The only problem is whith this part (above 37.4375em):

```css
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .FlexCtaBanner--innerWrapper {
    flex-basis: 12rem;
  }
  .FlexCtaBanner-image {
    flex-basis: 12rem !important;
  }
}
```

In the edge cases for vertical images, I'd like for the image to align to the left. Is it possible without nesting it inside another div?

**Constraints:**

- not introduce new HTML elements;
- not set extra media queries;

```css
.rounded-lg {
  border-radius: 0.5rem !important;
}
.box-shadow-1 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.1),
    0 2px 8px -1px rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.2) !important;
}
.display-flex {
  display: flex !important;
}
.flex-direction-column {
  flex-direction: column !important;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .sm\:flex-direction-row {
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }
}
.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .sm\:align-items-center {
    align-items: center !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .sm\:justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
}
.align-self-flex-start {
  align-self: flex-start !important;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .sm\:align-self-auto {
    align-self: auto !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62.4375em) {
  .md\:align-self-flex-start {
    align-self: flex-start !important;
  }
}
.flex-initial {
  flex: 0 1 auto !important;
}
.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
.flex-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 1 !important;
}
.gap-y-4 {
  row-gap: 1rem !important;
}
.gap-x-10 {
  -moz-column-gap: 2.5rem !important;
  column-gap: 2.5rem !important;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .sm\:gap-y-0 {
    row-gap: 0 !important;
  }
  .sm\:gap-x-10 {
    -moz-column-gap: 2.5rem !important;
    column-gap: 2.5rem !important;
  }
}
.max-w-none {
  max-width: none !important;
}
.max-h-32 {
  max-height: 8rem !important;
}
.p-4 {
  padding: 1rem !important;
}
.m-0 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .sm\:px-4 {
    padding-left: 1rem !important;
    padding-right: 1rem !important;
  }
  .sm\:ml-8 {
    margin-left: 2rem !important;
  }
}
.type-body-one {
  line-height: 1.75 !important;
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  letter-spacing: -0.0125rem !important;
  font-family: "CircularStd-Book", Arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}
.type-body-one::before,
.type-body-one::after {
  content: "" !important;
  display: block !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
}
.type-body-one::before {
  margin-bottom: calc(-0.375em + 0px) !important;
}
.type-body-one::after {
  margin-top: calc(-0.375em + 0px) !important;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .type-body-one {
    line-height: 1.75 !important;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    letter-spacing: -0.015625rem !important;
  }
  .type-body-one::before,
  .type-body-one::after {
    content: "" !important;
    display: block !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    width: 0 !important;
  }
  .type-body-one::before {
    margin-bottom: calc(-0.40625em + 0px) !important;
  }
  .type-body-one::after {
    margin-top: calc(-0.40625em + 0px) !important;
  }
}
.font-bold {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}
.leading-6 {
  line-height: 1.5rem !important;
}

@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .FlexCtaBanner {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.FlexCtaBanner--innerWrapper {
  -moz-column-gap: 4.125rem;
  column-gap: 4.125rem;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .FlexCtaBanner--innerWrapper {
    flex-basis: 12rem;
  }
  .FlexCtaBanner-image {
    flex-basis: 12rem !important;
  }
}
.FlexCtaBanner-text {
  text-wrap: balance;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .FlexCtaBanner-text {
    flex-basis: 18rem;
  }
}
.FlexCtaBanner-cta {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .FlexCtaBanner-cta {
    justify-self: end;
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-cy="ugcCollectionBanner-291f9ea3-1636-43b7-9ea6-fe75b6edb462" class="FlexCtaBanner display-flex flex-direction-column sm:flex-direction-row flex-wrap sm:align-items-center sm:justify-content-center gap-y-4 gap-x-10 sm:gap-x-10 sm:gap-y-0 p-4 bg-white box-shadow-1 sm:px-4 rounded-lg">
    <div class="FlexCtaBanner--innerWrapper display-flex flex-direction-column flex-grow flex-shrink sm:flex-direction-row flex-wrap sm:align-items-center gap-y-4">
        <img class="FlexCtaBanner-image display-flex flex-initial align-self-flex-start sm:align-self-auto md:align-self-flex-start max-w-48 max-h-32" src="https://dev.bankrate.com/f/166230/1729x2500/4bd76da4b8/mock_content_logo_vertical01.svg" alt="CTAWe want to know what you think about {THING}">
        <div class="FlexCtaBanner-text flex-grow flex-shrink">
            <h3 class="type-body-one font-bold text-black leading-6 m-0 mb-2">We want to know what you think about {THING}</h3>
            <p class="m-0 text-slate leading-6">Have experience with {THING}? Let us know your thoughts.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- htmlmin:ignore -->
    <button class="FlexCtaBanner-cta Button Button--primary max-w-none sm:ml-8 " data-beam-element-clicked="" id="UGC_review_entrypoint_small" data-type="button" data-location="UGC_review_entrypoint_small" data-position="1" data-text="Review this" data-outcome="open_review_questions" data-beam-uid="2" data-beam-event="click">
    Write review
    </button>
    <!-- htmlmin:ignore -->
</div>
```

Comment: Post your [mcve] in your question, not on codepen please

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: When I see `!important;` in CSS it most often means too much CSS or something is "wrong" with the setup.

Comment: Problem is that it was coded with an in-house CSS library that uses as default !important flags, so any style that needs to be overridden, must carry the !important flag. This is kind of the "extracted" code.

Comment: You can remove a _lot_ of the styles you've left here and still show the layout problem. We don't need to wade through several feet of button styles, for example. Please make it easier for your volunteer helpers to see the problem. Also, your title should be a clear, _specific_ question.

Comment: Why are you styling the image with `flex-basis` anyway? Does anything break if you just remove that declaration?

Comment: Yes. I'd like a specific gap between the image and the text with either a horizontal image or a vertical image (desktop dimensions).

Comment: Sounds like you need to edit that "an in-house CSS library that uses as default !important flags" rather than trying to "piled on the dung heap" here.